# Identify element using multiple classes in random arrangement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there a way to get the element using its classes not knowing the arrangement of classes?

I have here a sample HTML

```
<table>
  <tr class="header first test1">
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="header first test2">
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="h34der third test1">
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I need to get the element that has **header** and **test1** as its classes

Options I did was the following:

Option #1

```
$('.header, .test1').css('background','yellow');
```

However it is incorrect as it color all the elements that has "header" or "test1" class.

Option #2
 I saw that this is possible

```
$("[class*='header first test1']").css('background','yellow');
```

But my scenario was I do not know the class "first" and the only classes I know are "header" and "test1".

Is there a way to identify the element using multiple classes?
Appreciate your help with this.

Here is my fiddle I used for testing: http://jsfiddle.net/ky8d94n6/

Comment: `$('.header.test1')`

Comment: Do some research before posting a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$('.header.test1')` to select element will class `header` and `test1`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.header.test1').css('background','yellow');
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.header.test1').css('background','yellow');
});
```

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="header first test1">
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="header first test2">
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="h34der third test1">
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```